# X Motif client not applying scrollbars to a RowCol widget as expected

Tags: c, x11, motif

I have a C client for X Motif that is not showing the scrollbars for a Row Col widget as expected.  The main window (toplevel) has a form added to it.  In the form I add a label gadget as a top attachment to the left side.  Then, I add a Quit button as a top attachment to the right side.

Then I add a ScrolledWindow widget and attach it to the form as a bottom attachment to the left side.  I specify the height, width and scrollbar policy value as:

```
sw = XtVaCreateManagedWidget("scrolled_w", xmScrolledWidgetWidgetClass, form,
       XmNwidth, 575,
       XmNheight,  120,
       XmNscrollingPolicy, XmAUTOMATIC,
       XmNscrollBarDisplayPolicy, XmAS_NEEDED, NULL);
```

Inside the sw widget I create a row col widget and add a bunch of buttons
to it.  They are displaying fine and going in using the orientation desired.

```
rowcol = XmCreateRowColumn(sw, "rowcolumn", NULL, 0);

 XtVaGetValues(rowcol, XmNforeground, &fg, XmNbackground, &bg,
               XmNborderColor, &bord, NULL);

XtVaSetValues(rowcol, XmNpacking, XmPACK_COLUMN,
                       XmNnumColumns, COLS,
                       XmNorientation, XmHORIZONTAL,
                       NULL);
```

The issue is when I resize the main X window, I "expect" that scrollbars 
should be applied to the row col window when the size of the main window is
not letting the entire scrolled window display.  But it doesn't.  The only
way I can get the scroll bars to show is if I rejig the XmNwidth and XmNheight
values for the creation of the window.

Any idea why this is happening?

thx.
W.

Comment: Please post the minimum self-contained code fragment that reproduces the issue. It's hard to tell what's happening w/o looking at the code.

Comment: `/* get the X environment initialized and setup */
  toplevel = XtVaOpenApplication(&app, client_type, NULL, 0, &g_argc, arg_vector, NULL, sessionShellWidgetClass, NULL);`

Comment: Please edit the question instead, and be sure to use markup.

Comment: I cannot post the code as it exceeds the limits on this site.

Comment: If you give me an email address I'll send the source in its entirety...if you want.  no spam.

Comment: edited as requested.